# How to add a "search bar " bundle or funtion in a Symfony 2 app

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

I wanna add a search bar composant to filter my results of searching.  Actually I have just a function which gives me all the data from DB.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('MaisonMaisonBundle:Maison')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

I want to just add an SQL request which gives me a filtered result, even a search bar bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given very little information. Still i will try to help you.

Use [Doctrine Query Builder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

For example;

```
// Add this after your namespace
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

// Modify your indexAction like below
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    // call for the query builder
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb
        ->select('m')
        ->from('MaisonMaisonBundle:Maison', 'm')
        ->where($qb->expr()->like('m.title', ':title'))
        ->setParameter('title', '%'.$request->get('keyword').'%'); // use $request->request->get('keyword') if you are using post method instead get with the form.

    $entities = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    //$entities = $em->getRepository('MaisonMaisonBundle:Maison')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks a ot that may be usefull